# Diebold Mariano test for non time-series data

Tags: time-series, cross-section, diebold-mariano-test

Can the Diebold Mariano test be used to compare the MSE of two models (trained on the same data) for non time series data?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it can.** There is nothing in the construction of the test that would make it unsuitable for non time series data. However, note the following subtlety: the test is for **comparing forecasts, not models**. As Diebold puts it in his ["Comparing Predictive Accuracy, Twenty Years Later: A Personal Perspective on the Use
and Abuse of Diebold–Mariano Tests"](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07350015.2014.983236) (2015) paper (ungated version [here](https://www.sas.upenn.edu/%7Efdiebold/papers/paper113/Diebold_DM%20Test.pdf)),

> The Diebold–Mariano (DM) test was intended for comparing forecasts; it has been, and remains, useful in that regard. The DM test was not intended for comparing models. Much of the large ensuing literature, however, uses DM-type tests for comparing models, in pseudo-out-of-sample environments. In that case, simpler yet more compelling full-sample model comparison procedures exist; they have been, and should continue to be, widely used. The hunch that pseudo-out-of-sample analysis is somehow the “only,” or “best,” or even necessarily a “good” way to provide insurance against in-sample overfitting in model comparisons proves largely false. On the other hand, pseudo-out-of-sample analysis remains useful for certain tasks, perhaps most notably for providing information about comparative predictive performance during particular historical episodes.